# How to enable CardView in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-cardview

I have tried using CardView in ViewPager and everytime I swipe left/right on CardView it goes to the next screen. I want the card to delete itself then. Currently as a standalone both are working fine but when I combine then only viewpager is working and not cardswipe dismiss.

I tried to disable ViewPager with the code below but this code also disables CardView swipe gestures. How can I make only CardView to have gesture and when you swipe in between 2 cards then its should have ViewPager as its not connected to card element.

Or disable ViewPager completely and use it as buttons and enable swipe on CardView. I really appreciate any help. Thanks in Advance.

FYI: I have tried android_horizontal_listview in ViewPager and that works fine and exactly like this.

For ViewPager:

```
mPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{           
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```

For CardView:

```
SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener swipeTouchListener =

new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener(mRecyclerView,
    new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener.SwipeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean canSwipe(int position) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismissedBySwipeLeft(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                mItems.remove(position);
                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismissedBySwipeRight(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                mItems.remove(position);
                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(swipeTouchListener);
```

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {


    ViewPager vp;
    View viewpager_layout_1;
    View viewpager_layout_2;
    View viewpager_layout_3;
    ActionBar.Tab tab_1;
    ActionBar.Tab tab_2;
    ActionBar.Tab tab_3;
    ActionBar bar;
    /////
    String jsonstring1;
    CardViewAdapter spinnerArray;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();//
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> array_list1;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RelativeLayout re1;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;


        viewpager_layout_1 = new View(mContext);
        viewpager_layout_1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sample1, null);


        viewpager_layout_3 = new View(mContext);
        viewpager_layout_3 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sample2, null);


        viewpager_layout_2 = new View(mContext);
        viewpager_layout_2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sample3, null);


        vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp);
        bar = getActionBar();


        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        Vector<View> pages = new Vector<View>();

        pages.add(viewpager_layout_1);
        pages.add(viewpager_layout_3);
        pages.add(viewpager_layout_2);

        CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(mContext, pages);
        vp.setAdapter(adapter);

        vp.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        tab_1 = bar.newTab();
        tab_1.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout_1);
        tab_1.setTabListener(this);
        bar.addTab(tab_1);


        tab_2 = bar.newTab();
        tab_2.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout_2);
        tab_2.setTabListener(this);
        bar.addTab(tab_2);


        tab_3 = bar.newTab();
        tab_3.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout_3);
        tab_3.setTabListener(this);
        bar.addTab(tab_3);


        ////


        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(MainActivity.this));


        jsonstring1 = "[{\"category\":\"1\",\"no\":\"1\",\"image\":\"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Jordan_by_Lipofsky_16577.jpg\"},{\"category\":\"2\",\"no\":\"2\",\"image\":\"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/96/Basketball_World_Cup_2014.jpg/800px-Basketball_World_Cup_2014.jpg\"},{\"category\":\"3\",\"no\":\"3\",\"image\":\"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Basketball_Goal.jpg\"},{\"category\":\"4\",\"no\":\"4\",\"image\":\"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Basketball_through_hoop.jpg\"}]";

        //////////

        array_list1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        JSONArray arr = null;
        try {
            arr = new JSONArray(jsonstring1);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject e1 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                String category = e1.getString("category").trim();
                String no = e1.getString("no").trim();
                String image = e1.getString("image").trim();

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("category", category);
                map.put("no", no);
                map.put("image", image);
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                array_list1.add(map);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        OnItemTouchListener itemTouchListener = new OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCardViewTap(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tapped " + array_list1.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onButton1Click(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Button1 in " + array_list1.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onButton2Click(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Button2 in " + array_list1.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        spinnerArray = new CardViewAdapter(itemTouchListener, MainActivity.this, array_list1);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) viewpager_layout_3.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        SlideInBottomAnimationAdapter alphaAdapter = new SlideInBottomAnimationAdapter(spinnerArray);
        ScaleInAnimationAdapter alphaAdapter2 = new ScaleInAnimationAdapter(alphaAdapter);
        final AlphaInAnimationAdapter alphaAdapter3 = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(alphaAdapter2);
        alphaAdapter3.setDuration(500);
        alphaAdapter3.setFirstOnly(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(alphaAdapter3);


        final SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener swipeTouchListener =
                new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener(recyclerView,
                        new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener.SwipeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean canSwipe(int position) {
                                return true;
                            }


                            @Override
                            public void onDismissedBySwipeLeft(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
//                                    mItems.remove(position);
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, array_list1.get(position) + " swiped left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    array_list1.remove(position);
                                    alphaAdapter3.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                }
                                alphaAdapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismissedBySwipeRight(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
//
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, array_list1.get(position) + " swiped right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    array_list1.remove(position);
                                    alphaAdapter3.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                }
                                alphaAdapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(swipeTouchListener);


    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), tab.toString(), 5).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), tab.toString(), 5).show();
        vp.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {


            tab_2.setCustomView(null);
            tab_2.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout_2);

            tab_1.setCustomView(null);
            tab_1.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout_1);


            tab_3.setCustomView(null);
            tab_3.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout_33);


        } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {


            tab_2.setCustomView(null);
            tab_2.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout_22);

            tab_1.setCustomView(null);
            tab_1.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout_1);


            tab_3.setCustomView(null);
            tab_3.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout_3);


        } else if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {

            tab_1.setCustomView(null);
            tab_1.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout_11);


            if (tab_2 != null) {

                tab_2.setCustomView(null);
                tab_2.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout_2);
            }


            if (tab_3 != null) {

                tab_3.setCustomView(null);
                tab_3.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout_3);
            }


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), tab.toString(), 5).show();

    }


    public interface OnItemTouchListener {

        // this will disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view


        /**
         * Callback invoked when the user Taps one of the RecyclerView items
         *
         * @param view     the CardView touched
         * @param position the index of the item touched in the RecyclerView
         */
        public void onCardViewTap(View view, int position);

        /**
         * Callback invoked when the Button1 of an item is touched
         *
         * @param view     the Button touched
         * @param position the index of the item touched in the RecyclerView
         */
        public void onButton1Click(View view, int position);

        /**
         * Callback invoked when the Button2 of an item is touched
         *
         * @param view     the Button touched
         * @param position the index of the item touched in the RecyclerView
         */
        public void onButton2Click(View view, int position);
    }

    public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private final Context mContext;
        private final Vector<View> pages;

        public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, Vector<View> pages) {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.pages = pages;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            View page = pages.get(position);
            container.addView(page);


            return page;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return pages.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view.equals(object);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }


    }

    public class CardViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d;
        Activity a;
        private List<String> cards;
        private OnItemTouchListener onItemTouchListener2;


        public CardViewAdapter(OnItemTouchListener onItemTouchListener, Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
            //  this.cards = cards;
            this.onItemTouchListener2 = onItemTouchListener;
            this.a = a;
            this.d = d;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
            //  viewHolder.title.setText(cards.get(i));

            HashMap<String, String> item = d.get(i);
            viewHolder.title.setText(item.get("category"));
            imageLoader.displayImage(item.get("image"), viewHolder.im2);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            //   return d == null ? 0 : d.size();
            return (null != d ? d.size() : 0);
            // return d.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            MotionEvent motionEvent;
            private int mSlop;
            private int mMinFlingVelocity;
            private int mMaxFlingVelocity;
            private long mAnimationTime;
            // Fixed properties
            //   private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
            private SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener.SwipeListener mSwipeListener;

            // Transient properties
            private int mViewWidth = 1; // 1 and not 0 to prevent dividing by zero
            private int mDismissAnimationRefCount = 0;
            private float mAlpha;
            private float mDownX;
            private float mDownY;
            private boolean mSwiping;
            private int mSwipingSlop;
            private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
            private int mDownPosition;
            private int mAnimatingPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
            private View mDownView;
            private boolean mPaused;
            private float mFinalDelta;
            ///
            private TextView title;
            private Button button1;
            private Button button2;
            private ImageView im2;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_title);

                im2 = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            }
        }
    }


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout_1">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout_1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            />


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

sample2.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/re1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `ViewPager` is not optimal for Tinder clones. Try https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards or https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards.

Comment: But how can I make it work? I am using https://github.com/brnunes/SwipeableRecyclerView .But I would like to use in a viewpager.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue I used an `ItemTouchHelper` provided by `Android` to easily swipe to delete an item from a `RecyclerView`.

Please see implementation below:

**MainActivity**:

Here I have the implementation of the `ViewPager` and it's child `Fragments`.

```
package za.co.gadgetgirl.testcardpager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        Frag1 frag1 = new Frag1();
        Frag2 frag2 = new Frag2();
        Frag3 frag3 = new Frag3();

        adapter.addFragment(frag1, "frag1");
        adapter.addFragment(frag2, "frag2");
        adapter.addFragment(frag3, "frag3");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

**Frag1**:

On this `Fragment` I have a `RecyclerView` that has an `ItemTouchHelper` attached. The `ItemTouchHelper` listens for the `onSwiped(...)` method that is defined in the `SimpleCallback` interface and I just remove the swiped item in this method.

```
package za.co.gadgetgirl.testcardpager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Frag1 extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);

        final RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rv);
        final LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        final RVAdapter rvAdapter = new RVAdapter(Person.initializeData());
        rv.setAdapter(rvAdapter);

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT|ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                rvAdapter.removeItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv);

        return v;
    }

}
```

**RVAdapter**:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {


    //...implementation...

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        persons.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}
```

To use the `ItemTouchHelper`, you will need the `appcompat-v7:22.2.0` dependency and above defined in your app gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use `SwipeableRecyclerView` before so I cannot really say much. I have a problem same as you before. I solve it by handling `onTouch` event of the base container of fragment (such as `LinearLayout`,`RelativeLayout`) and it work for me. Why don't you try this solution and get back to us

Comment: Have you also try overriding onInterceptTouchEvent() method of SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener ?

Comment: Can you share a snippet code for the same.I am using  pager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); but its disabling entire view-pager.How did you handle it ?

Comment: I have 3 base containers.Tab1 ,Tab2 and Tab3 all relative layouts and has recyclerview and viewpager with cardview in it.

Comment: @jason , the code is actually simple. In my case the base container of the fragement is _RelativeLayout1_

 `public void onActivityCreated(Bundle paramBundle) {
  super.onActivityCreated(paramBundle);
   RelativeLayout relativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) this.parentLinear
    .findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
relativeLayout1.setOnTouchListener(this);
 }
          
 @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
  case R.id.RelativeLayout1:
   return true;
   break;
  default:
   break;
  }
  return false;
 }`

Comment: Its not working even now.I have 3 tabs and all 3 have cardviewpager inside it and viewpager in in the main layout.so everytime I swipe it goes to next tab and card swipe functionality is not performed .How can I implement that.I tried the code above with relative layout in main layout and also relativelayout in middle tab and both of them display same result .Basically nothing changed.Can anyone help me out here.Thanks.

Comment: @jason ,Does your cardviewpager use all the space in the tab with `android:layout_height="match_parent"` ?

Comment: Should I post the entire code here with tabs and xml ? .You can run the project also.

Comment: @jason, it will be great if you could post the entire code. If it is possible can you also post your program code so I can look up which event you are listening for such as `onTouch` event and so on.

Comment: I have updated the Q .Please take a look and let me know how I can fix it.I really appreciate the help.Thanks.

Comment: @jason , correct me if I am wrong your layout is similar as to pseudo code as below.

`<View Pager>

     <Layout With Tab>
              <Card Viewer/>
              <Card Viewer/>
               <Card Viewer/>
     </Layout With Tab>

     
       <Layout With Tab>
              <Card Viewer/>
              <Card Viewer/>
               <Card Viewer/>
     </Layout With Tab>


       <Layout With Tab>
              <Card Viewer/>
              <Card Viewer/>
               <Card Viewer/>
     </Layout With Tab>

</View Pager>`

Comment: @jason , can you also post a screen shot of your layout.

Comment: @jason , by looking at your code I feel that you have some layout problem. By layout problem , I mean that you are not seeing the view that you think you saw because of view which are very similar. Can you try confirming that what you see in the screen is what you really intended to see ? I will be bad if you spend a lot of hour trying to debug the problem while only founding out that your code actually work all along.

Comment: @jason , Is there any reason why you should use SwipeableRecyclerView ? you could try out Swipeable-Cards  as suggested above or find a similar library [here](http://android-arsenal.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For the use case that you are describing, I don't think that ViewPager is the class that you want to use to get your swipe action. It seems to me that the combination of [CoordinatorLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) and [SwipeDismissBehavior](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/SwipeDismissBehavior.html) is more appropriate.

**EDIT:**
See my solution below:

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView);

        SwipeDismissBehavior<CardView> behavior = new SwipeDismissBehavior();
        behavior.setSwipeDirection(SwipeDismissBehavior.SWIPE_DIRECTION_START_TO_END);
        behavior.setListener(new SwipeDismissBehavior.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(View view) {
                finish(); // close activity if desired 
            }

            @Override
            public void onDragStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) cardView.getLayoutParams()).setBehavior(behavior);
    }
}
```

Also, here are some examples of using the [CoordinatorLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html):

- [How to use SwipeDismissBehavior.OnDismissListener on RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549703/how-to-use-swipedismissbehavior-ondismisslistener-on-recyclerview)
- [CoordinatorLayout using the ViewPager's RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540632/coordinatorlayout-using-the-viewpagers-recyclerview)
- https://lab.getbase.com/introduction-to-coordinator-layout-on-android/
- http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

I haven't been able to find many examples using [SwipeDismissBehavior](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/SwipeDismissBehavior.html) specifically, but the concepts are similar to the links above.

Alternatively, you may also be able to follow the suggestions of a similar post:
[Android swipe layout to dismiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641966/android-swipe-layout-to-dismiss) to get the results you desire.

Hope this helps.